# Polymorphic many-to-many association error in Ruby On Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, polymorphic-associations

I am struggling with a polymorphic many-to-many association in rails 3.

My Article model looks like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_tags
  has_many :people, :through => :article_tags, :source => :taggable, :source_type => :person
end
```

My ArticleTag model looks like this:

```
class ArticleTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

My Person model looks like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_tags, :as => :taggable
end
```

Finally, my Organization model looks like this:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_tags, :as => :taggable
end
```

I have a schema which looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110322234836) do

  create_table "article_tags", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "articles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.date     "published_on"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "people", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "organizations", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

I was hoping that this would allow me to create people and organizations relationships from my articles like this:

```
Article.create!
Article.first.people.create!
```

and hopefully to be able to access it the other way afterwards by

```
Person.first.articles
```

Unfortunately I get an error when I try to add a person this way:

```
Article.first.people.create!

NameError: uninitialized constant Article::person
.../base.rb:1199:in `compute_type'
.../reflection.rb:162:in `klass'
.../association_collection.rb:157:in `transaction'
.../has_many_through_association.rb:41:in `create_record'
.../has_many_through_association.rb:13:in `create!
```

Any help would be very much appreciated I've tried many alternatives but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just had to some something similar to this recently. It looks like most of your code is right although in mine for the first section I would try changing do this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_tags
  has_many :people, :through => :article_tags, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "Person"
end
```

Also you can't do: `Article.first.people.create({:name => "Tim"})`
You would have to assign it to a variable first:

```
article = Article.first
article.people.create({:name => "Tim"})
```

Let me know if this works for you. I just skimmed through. If it doesn't i can double check my code again and see if there are any other differences.

Comment: Hi Joshua, Many Thanks - I tried and changing the source_type and it now seems to work as it should. 

Just in case anyone else is struggling to achieve this it might be worth noting that the Person & Organization models need another has_many :articles, :through => :article_tags to make sure that the relationship works from both sides.

Finally make sure you have an article_id column in article_tags table too.

Comment: No problem. I had to struggle with polymorphic many-to-many associations on a site i just worked on. I have about twenty going both ways and it def gets confusing.